# Angular JS & TypeScript - Error: ng:areq Bad Argument "Argument 'XXXXXX' is not a function, got undefined"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

Keep getting an error specified in the title.

I split models and controllers into separate files stored under models and controllers directories respectively.

When I tried to link them up, I got an error saying "**ng:areq Bad Argument  "Argument 'rightPaneCtrl' is not a function, got undefined**".

What's wrong with my code?

**index.html↓**

```
<html ng-app="rightpaneMVC" data-framework="typescript">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <!--<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->
    <style>
        .item_list {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            padding-left: 0;
        }

            .item_list > li {
                list-style-type: none;
                cursor: pointer;
                border: 1px solid black;
                padding: 0.3rem;
                width: 100px;
                margin-right: 0.2rem;
            }
    </style>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="tab-category" ng-controller="rightPaneCtrl">
        <!--<ul>
            <li ng-repeat="tab in vm.tabs track by $index" ng-click="vm.handleTabClick(tab,$index)">
                <a href="#{{ tab.tabID }}">{{ tab.name }}{{ tab.tabID }}</a>
                <span ng:class="{true:'ui-icon ui-icon-circle-close ui-closable-tab', false:''}[$index!=0]"></span>
            </li>
        </ul>-->
        <hr />
        <tabset ng-init="startActive = true">
            <tab ng-repeat="tab in vm.tabs track by $index" active="startActive">
                <tab-heading ng-switch="tab.isClosable">
                    <div ng-switch-when=true>
                        {{ tab.name }} <a ng-click="vm.handleTabClick($index)" href=''><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-switch-when=false>
                        {{ tab.name }}
                    </div>
                </tab-heading>
                <ul class="item_list" ng-switch="tab.categoryTypeString">

                    <li ng-switch-when="DAI" ng-repeat="item in tab.items" ng-click="vm.handleItemClick(item)">
                        <img ng-src="{{item.thumbnailPath}}"><br />
                        <p align="center">{{ item.categoryName }}</p>
                    </li>
                    <li ng-switch-when="CHU" ng-repeat="item in tab.items" ng-click="vm.handleItemClick(item)">
                        <img ng-src="{{item.thumbnailPath}}"><br />
                        <p align="center">{{ item.categoryName }}</p>
                    </li>
                    <li ng-switch-default ng-repeat="item in tab.items">
                        <img ng-src="{{item.thumbnailPath}}"><br />
                        <p align="center">{{ item.categoryName }}</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </tab>
        </tabset>


        <!--<div ng-repeat="tab in vm.tabs track by $index" id="{{ tab.tabID }}">

                <ul class="item_list" ng-switch="tab.categoryTypeString">
                    <li ng-switch-when="DAI" ng-repeat="item in tab.items" ng-click="vm.handleItemClick(item)"> {{ item.categoryName }}</li>
                    <li ng-switch-when="CHU" ng-repeat="item in tab.items" ng-click="vm.handleItemClick(item)"> {{ item.categoryName }}</li>
                    <li ng-switch-default ng-repeat="item in tab.items"> {{ item.categoryName }}</li>
                </ul>
            </div>-->
    </div>

    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.4.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Application.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers/RightPaneCtrl.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Application.ts↓**

```
module rightpane {

    'use strict';

    angular.module('rightpaneMVC', ['ui.bootstrap']);
    angular.module('rightpaneMVC').controller('rightPaneCtrl', RightPaneCtrl);
}
```

**RightPaneCtrl.ts↓**

```
 module rightpane {

        'use strict';

        export class RightPaneCtrl {        

            public static $inject = ['$scope', '$http'];        

            private mModel = new RightPaneTabList;        

            public constructor(

                private $scope: any,
                private $http: ng.IHttpService) {

                $scope.vm = this;        
            }        

            public get tabs(): Tab[] {
                return this.mModel.tabs;
            }        

            handleItemClick(aItem: Item): void {
                console.log('Item clicked');
                this.mModel.addCategory(aItem);
            }        

            handleTabClick(tabIndex: number): void {
                console.log('Tab clicked');
                this.mModel.tabs.splice(tabIndex, 1);
            }        
        }        
    }
```

**Directory Structure↓**

```
root
    |-index.html
    |-controllers
        |-RightPaneCtrl.ts
```

Comment: I like Related sessions show so many same error with this - http://i.imgur.com/jF0jpYk.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, we had some progress with [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31100509/1679310). But now new issues appeared and OP created this plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/WLH1GgLlpE7nek1poWnA?p=preview

With this error message:

> TypeError: rightpane.RightPaneTabList is not a function
>       at new RightPaneCtrl (RightPaneCtrl.js:14) ...

There is updated and [partially working version](http://plnkr.co/edit/sFxVrEHjlmDw1J6h4xDz?p=preview). The problem was ... missing components loaded into the browser... When we create documents like this

enums/ECategoryType.js
   models/Item.js
   models/Tab.js
   models/RightPaneTabList.js
   controllers/RightPaneCtrl.js
   Application.js

We have to append all of them (and in correct order) into the page code:

```
<script src="enums/ECategoryType.js"></script>
<script src="models/Item.js"></script>
<script src="models/Tab.js"></script>
<script src="models/RightPaneTabList.js"></script>
<script src="controllers/RightPaneCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="Application.js"></script>
```

*(there are missing images, but app should start)*

Comment: You nailed the problem down!
Now everything is working smoothly...

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: That is amazing! Great to see that, Enjoy mighty Angular with Typescript... great choice ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues. There is [a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Hxiwqxi4Uhfy5WyIABKW?p=preview), showing the changes below in action (simplified version, just to make it running)

Firtly, if we want to use some class.. it already must be loaded, so we must change order of these scripts

```
// here we must make JS aware about our Ctrl
<script src="controllers/RightPaneCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="Application.js"></script> 
// here it would be too late
// <script src="controllers/RightPaneCtrl.js"></script>
```

And also, becase our Controller has module/namespace:

```
module rightpane {        
    export class RightPaneCtrl {
    ...
```

We must assign it with its full name:

```
angular.module('rightpaneMVC')
    // instead of this
    // .controller('rightPaneCtrl', RightPaneCtrl);
    // wee need this
    .controller('rightPaneCtrl', rightpane.RightPaneCtrl);
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Hxiwqxi4Uhfy5WyIABKW?p=preview)

Comment: Your solution seems to have resolved the problem, but now another error has come up saying "TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at new RightPaneCtrl". I just modified the bits you pointed out and left other code untouched...

Comment: Well, either you can change my plunker to show the problem, or you should define new Question here... Because I did my best to help you to find out what is wrong based on the Current Question... I am trying to say... another error is about another issue, right? But if you can show me that error in my plunker... I am ready to assist. If you create new question.. you will get larger audience for your NEW issue.. does it make sense?

Comment: I have reproduced my code on Plunker. I'm new to this tool and not sure If I properly created files on the site...
Please take a look.[Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/WLH1GgLlpE7nek1poWnA?p=preview).

Comment: You did a great job... great to see your plunker... I will try to check it but cannot guarantee time... will try to come to you ASAP

Comment: I observed your code, made few fixes, and create new plunker and described that all in new answer... hope now you have all ... ;)

Comment: I really appreciate your help!
Now my code is working smoothly!

Comment: @user1111 this is great to see. In case you think this stuff helped a bit, you can also up-vote  - read more ["Why is voting important"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) ... and about [your reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reputation)